# Can't install wine: "unmet dependencies"

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dependencies

I'm trying to install wine. I followed the installation instructions at https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu (focal), but when I run `$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`, I get the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dconf-gsettings-backend : Depends: dconf-service (>= 0.36.0-1)
                           Depends: dconf-service (< 0.36.0-1.1~)
 policykit-1 : Depends: dbus
               Depends: libpam-systemd but it is not going to be installed
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 6.0.0~focal-1)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Using Synaptic Package Manager, it wants to remove quite a lot of packages (the list starts with `accountsservice, acpi-support, acpid`), which is certainly not what I want.

Comment: Look like you are trying to install a version of Wine that is not compatible with your release of Ubuntu. Uninstall the packages that you have already installed, delete the sources you added. Then start over, paying close attention that you follow the correct instructions for your release of Ubuntu. Alternately, you can install Wine from the Ubuntu repositories, which is already matched to your release of Ubuntu.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks for your reply! Disabling http://ppa.launchpad.net/sane-project/sane-git/ubuntu source worked and I could install wine. Out of interest: Can you tell me why it didn't work with this repository enabled?

Comment: Too many non-Ubuntu sources create a Frankensystem. It's no longer Ubuntu, it's not really anything else, it's afraid of fire, and it's terribly unstable. Software from each source has different *dependencies*, and different developers didn't use uniform dependencies, creating the version conflict that you encountered. The purpose of a *Linux distro* like Ubuntu is a uniform set of dependencies leading to a stable system and easy software management. You abandoned that when you started adding non-Ubuntu sources. You're out in the wilderness now, and you need apt skills to survive.